# How to make this Mastermind solver use lesser guess

Tags: c

So, Mastermind is a game play by 2 players, one is a decoder another is an encoder. The encoder will choose 4 colors and position it as they want.Then, the decoder will try to guess what the encoder choose by using the 2 output that they’ll get after trying for a guess. The output is black and white peg. The black one is for correct position and correct color while the white one is for correct color but wrong position. The game end when the decoder get 4 black pegs which is all is correct.

This is my code right now.

It includes standard C libraries and defines a constant MINIMAX_TURNOFF.
There are utility functions for handling inputs, testing guesses against the secret code, and other operations to solve the game.
The main function initializes the game, generates a random secret code, and enters a loop for making guesses.
In each iteration, it tests the guess, updates the active possibilities, and decides whether to use the minimax algorithm or simply choose the first available possibility for the next guess.
The game continues for a maximum of 10 rounds or until the secret code is guessed correctly.
The game's progress and results are printed to the console.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MINIMAX_TURNOFF 5000

long min(long a, long b) { return a < b ? a : b; } // Check which number is leaster

bool handleInput(long input, int m, int p) {
  for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
    long num = input / pow(10, p - i - 1);
    if (num >= m || num < 0)
      return 0;
    input -= num * pow(10, p - i - 1);
  }
  return 1;
}

int testCode(long guess, long code, int p) { // Try to guess and get the result
  int g[p];
  int c[p];

  for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
    g[i] = guess / pow(10, p - i - 1);
    guess -= g[i] * pow(10, p - i - 1);
    c[i] = code / pow(10, p - i - 1);
    code -= c[i] * pow(10, p - i - 1);
  }

  int occurring[11] = {0};
  for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
    occurring[g[i]]++;
  }
  int occurringC[11] = {0};
  for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
    occurringC[c[i]]++;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 11; ++i) {
    occurring[i] = min(occurring[i], occurringC[i]);
  }

  int blacks = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
    if (g[i] == c[i]) {
      blacks++;
      occurring[g[i]]--;
    }
  }
  int whites = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 11; ++i) {
    if (occurring[i] != 0)
      whites += occurring[i];
  }
  return blacks * 10 + whites;
}

long composeNum(long j, int m) {
  long r = j % m;
  long b = j / m;
  int d = 1;
  while (b != 0) {
    r += (b % m) * pow(10, d);
    b = b / m;
    d++;
  }
  return r;
}

long countActive(bool *active, long length) { // return amount of the current active possibility
  long count = 0;
  for (long i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    if (active[i])
      count++;
  }
  return count;
}

long testNumber(long testingNumber, long *b, long length, bool *active, int p) { // calculate that is the number can be the answer
  long maximum = 0;
  for (long i = 0; i < p*10; i++) {
    long counter = 0;
    bool f = (composeNum(i, 5) / 10 + composeNum(i, 5)) < 5;
    for (long j = 0; j < length; j++) {
      if (active[j] && f) {
        if (testCode(testingNumber, b[j], p) == composeNum(i, 5)) {
          counter++;
        }
      }
    }
    if (counter > maximum) {
      maximum = counter;
    }
  }
  return maximum;
}

void setNumbersWithSameCodeActive(long number, long code, long *b, long length, bool *active, int p) { // set that this number still be the answer
  for (long i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    if (testCode(b[i], number, p) == code) {
      active[i] = 1;
    } else {
      active[i] = 0;
    }
  }
}

void excludeNumbersWithSameCode(long number, long code, long *b, long length, bool *active, int p) { // set the number that are not the same to be inactive
  for (long i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    if (active[i] && (testCode(b[i], number, p) != code)) {
      active[i] = 0;
    }
  }
}

long firstActive(long *b, long length, bool *active, int p) { // return the next guess by using the first value inside the possibility array
  long minimum = -1;
  long minimumNumber = -1;
  for (long i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    if (active[i]) {
      minimum = testNumber(b[i], b, length, active, p);
      minimumNumber = b[i];
      return minimumNumber;
    }
  }
  return minimumNumber;
}

long minimax(long *b, long length, bool *active, int p) { // calculate the next guess using minimax algorithm

  // Set initial minimum
  long minimumNumber = firstActive(b, length, active, p);
  long minimum = testNumber(minimumNumber, b, length, active, p);

  // Apply minimax
  for (long j = 0; j < length; j++) {
    if (!active[j])
      continue;
    else {
      long localMaximum = testNumber(b[j], b, length, active, p);
      if (localMaximum < minimum) {
        minimum = localMaximum;
        minimumNumber = b[j];
      }
    }
  }

  printf("\n");
  return minimumNumber;
}

void initArrayFromStartToEnd(long *a, long start, long end) { // init the array for all of the possibility
  for (long i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    a[i - start] = i;
  }
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL)); // Init for random the Secret Code

    int m = 6; // Init the number of color
    int p = 4; // Init the length of the Secret Code

    long start = 1111; // Init the least combination
    long end = 6666; // Init the Greatest combination

    long length = end - start + 1; // Init the length of the possibilty

    bool active[length]; // Declare the Boolean Array of the possibility that still active

    long b[length];
    initArrayFromStartToEnd(b, start, end); // Init all of the possibilty

    long input = 0; // Random the secret code
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int digit = (rand() % 6) + 1;
        input = input * 10 + digit;
    }
    printf("Secret code : %ld", input);

    long teste = 1122; // Declare the first guess

    for (int krok = 1; krok <= 10; krok++) { // Loop for 10 times krok = round
        int r = testCode(teste, input, p); // Test the guessing number to get the result
        printf("\n[%i] Testing code %li | Score %d\n", krok, teste, r);
        if (r == p * 10) {
            printf("You win.\n");
            break;
        }

        if (krok == 1)
            setNumbersWithSameCodeActive(teste, r, b, length, active, p); // To make a decision which one should be active or inactive
        else
            excludeNumbersWithSameCode(teste, r, b, length, active, p); // To delete the possible number which can't be an answer

        long newTeste;
        if (countActive(active, length) < MINIMAX_TURNOFF) { // If the active possibility is less than 5000 it will use minimax algorithm for the nextguess
            newTeste = minimax(b, length, active, p);
        } else {
            newTeste = firstActive(b, length, active, p); // if the active possibility is more than 5000 it will use the first possibility
        }
        teste = newTeste; // change the value for the next guess
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: "4 pegs"... Use `pow10[] = { 1, 10, 100, 1000 };` instead of `pow()` and the floating point math library. Your processor will run cooler... (Those are the first 4 powers of 10).

Comment: Clue: 1111 < 4798 < 6666... `4798` is not a legitimate possibility, yet this code assumes that it is... Before trying to improve the algorithm, look to the actual problem statement and write code that implements the situation correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The OP code starts off with an array of 6666 - 1111 = 5555 boolean (integer) elements all marked active (potential solutions). In fact, with 6 "colours" (digits) and 4 "holes" in the game board, there are only 6^4 (1296) legitimate combinations.

Even though processors run at breakneck speeds, using floating point library functions (`pow()`) and a base10 representation of the guesses (with base10 multiply, divide and modulo operations) is going to be slow (and will not scale).

To provide a fresh start, the following uses an array of only 1296x16 bit values. Each uint16 has its 4x4 bit nybbles assigned a value from 0x1 to 0x6. Thus the range is covered. The number of "colours" could be increased as high as 15 and still fit into the increased number of elements. The number of "holes" (pegs) could be increased to 8 (uint32) or 16 (uint64) without stress.

With this encoding, inexpensive bitwise operations can be used to *pick apart* any particular value (or *assemble* value(s) as shown in the code.)

This code makes several random guesses, and assesses the correctness of each. Code to evaluate the result and improve each guess is an exercise for another day (after much contemplation.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

uint16_t poss[ 6*6*6*6 ]; // 4 pegs used of 6 possible colours each
int nPoss = sizeof poss/sizeof poss[0];

void init_poss( void ) {
    size_t cnt = 0;

    // unconventional format for easy scanning
    for( int m = 1<<12; m <= 6<<12; m += 1<<12 )
    for( int c = 1<< 8; c <= 6<< 8; c += 1<< 8 )
    for( int x = 1<< 4; x <= 6<< 4; x += 1<< 4 )
    for( int i = 1<< 0; i <= 6<< 0; i += 1<< 0 )
        poss[cnt++] = m | c | x | i;
}

void assess( uint16_t guess, uint16_t ans, int *black, int *white ) {
    *black = 0;
    *white = 0;

    int tallyG[ 1 + 6 ] = { 0 }; // 1+6 because [0] is not used
    int tallyA[ 1 + 6 ] = { 0 };

    // loop comparing guessed val with answer val in each position.
    size_t i = 16;
    do {
        i -= 4; // 12, 8, 4, 0 is last
        int g = (guess >> i) & 0xF;
        int a = ( ans  >> i) & 0xF;

        *black += (g == a); // matches count as black

        tallyG[ g ] += (g != a); // non-matches tallied as guess and correct ans
        tallyA[ a ] += (g != a);
    } while( i > 0 );

    // white sums the lower of the guess tally or answer tally for each "colour"
    for( i = 1; i <= 6; i++ )
        *white += tallyG[i] < tallyA[i] ? tallyG[i] : tallyA[i];
}

int main( void ) {
    init_poss(); // Initialise array of all possible combinations

    size_t i = 0;
#if 0 // Set to 1 to output 72 lines of all possible variations
    while( i < nPoss ) {
        printf( "%X ", poss[ i++ ] ); // NB: Hex output of 4 nibble values
        if( i % 18 == 0 )
            putchar( '\n' );
    }
#endif

    srand( time( NULL ) );

// shift blocks of 4 bits & mask to get 4 bit value
#define V(x,b4) ( ((x) >> (b4 * 4)) & 0xF )

    // Pick a random answer
    uint16_t ans = poss[ i = rand() % nPoss ];

    printf( "Ans %4d reveal: %d-%d-%d-%d\n", i, V(ans,3), V(ans,2), V(ans,1), V(ans,0) );

    // Make some random guesses
    for( int x = 0; x < 10; x++ ) {
        uint16_t g = poss[ i = rand() % nPoss ]; // make a guess
        printf( "i = %4d: Guess: %d-%d-%d-%d - ", i, V(g,3), V(g,2), V(g,1), V(g,0) );

        int black, white;
        assess( g, ans, &black, &white );

        printf( "black( %d ), white( %d )\n", black, white );
        // ToDo: Analyse results and improve guessing each round
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Ans  299 reveal: 2-3-2-6
i =  801: Guess: 4-5-2-4 - black( 1 ), white( 0 )
i =  641: Guess: 3-6-5-6 - black( 1 ), white( 1 )
i = 1206: Guess: 6-4-4-1 - black( 0 ), white( 1 )
i =  294: Guess: 2-3-2-1 - black( 3 ), white( 0 )
i =  439: Guess: 3-1-2-2 - black( 1 ), white( 2 )
i = 1189: Guess: 6-4-1-2 - black( 0 ), white( 2 )
i =  798: Guess: 4-5-2-1 - black( 1 ), white( 0 )
i = 1020: Guess: 5-5-3-1 - black( 0 ), white( 1 )
i =  707: Guess: 4-2-4-6 - black( 1 ), white( 1 )
i = 1142: Guess: 6-2-5-3 - black( 0 ), white( 3 )
```

There are *magic numbers* scattered through this code. It's hoped the OP will recognise these values and their purpose.

Moving on, the following shows how each individual digit can be altered (incremented by one).

```
    uint16_t j, gx;

    printf( "Advance 1 step in table:\n" );
    j = (i+1)%nPoss;
    gx = poss[ j ];
    printf( "j = %4d: Guess: %d-%d-%d-%d - ", j, V(gx,3), V(gx,2), V(gx,1), V(gx,0) );
    assess( gx, ans, &black, &white );
    printf( "black( %d ), white( %d )\n", black, white );

    printf( "Advance 6 steps in table:\n" );
    j = (i+6)%nPoss;
    gx = poss[ j ];
    printf( "j = %4d: Guess: %d-%d-%d-%d - ", j, V(gx,3), V(gx,2), V(gx,1), V(gx,0) );
    assess( gx, ans, &black, &white );
    printf( "black( %d ), white( %d )\n", black, white );

    printf( "Advance 36 steps in table:\n" );
    j = (i+36)%nPoss;
    gx = poss[ j ];
    printf( "j = %4d: Guess: %d-%d-%d-%d - ", j, V(gx,3), V(gx,2), V(gx,1), V(gx,0) );
    assess( gx, ans, &black, &white );
    printf( "black( %d ), white( %d )\n", black, white );

    printf( "Advance 216 steps in table:\n" );
    j = (i+216)%nPoss;
    gx = poss[ j ];
    printf( "j = %4d: Guess: %d-%d-%d-%d - ", j, V(gx,3), V(gx,2), V(gx,1), V(gx,0) );
    assess( gx, ans, &black, &white );
    printf( "black( %d ), white( %d )\n", black, white );

    printf( "Increment first digit and decrement third (other two unchanged):\n" );
    j = (i + 216 - 6)%nPoss;
    gx = poss[ j ];
    printf( "j = %4d: Guess: %d-%d-%d-%d - ", j, V(gx,3), V(gx,2), V(gx,1), V(gx,0) );
    assess( gx, ans, &black, &white );
    printf( "black( %d ), white( %d )\n", black, white );
```

Output:

```
Ans   67 reveal: 1-2-6-2
i =  348: Guess: 2-4-5-1 - black( 0 ), white( 2 )
Advance 1 step in table:
j =  349: Guess: 2-4-5-2 - black( 1 ), white( 1 )
Advance 6 steps in table:
j =  354: Guess: 2-4-6-1 - black( 1 ), white( 2 )
Advance 36 steps in table:
j =  384: Guess: 2-5-5-1 - black( 0 ), white( 2 )
Advance 216 steps in table:
j =  564: Guess: 3-4-5-1 - black( 0 ), white( 1 )
Increment first digit and decrement third (other two unchanged):
j =  558: Guess: 3-4-4-1 - black( 0 ), white( 1 )
```

All that's left now is to assess which "hunch" paid off (which digit in which column registers as 'black' and which as 'white'.) Retain those thought to be 'black' and experiment with substitutions.

---

If anyone actually reads this, the "offsetting" done in the preceding block is actually hogwash. Each digit (nibble) must be isolated, operated-upon, then returned to the variable. This suggests a function like:
`void op( uint16_t *pVal, size_t dgtIdx, short plusMinusAmt );` 
left as an exercise for the reader.