# C uint16_t to padded hex string without libraries

Tags: arrays, c, string, data-conversion

I'm attempting to convert an `uint16_t` value to a hexadecimal representation of said number as a string of characters in C without using any external libraries. So far I've achieved a reliable conversion with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44549691/10035529) answer.
However, my use-case requires that the resulting output is padded with a leading zero, if the `uint16_t` value is smaller than `0x1000`. So for example, If i call the function like this:

```
char s[5];
itohexa(s, 1230); //(1230->0x04CE)
```

I'd get:

```
04CE
```

However, this function gives me this instead:

```
4CE
```

The actual number of bytes in an uint16_t represented in the string is important for my use case. I'm expecting the value to go over `0x0FFF` occasionally, So just adding a leading zero-character to any `uint16_t` number (which I've been doing as a workaround until now), wouldn't suffice.

Here's what I've tried:

```
static char *itohexa_helper(char *dest, uint16_t x, uint8_t pad) {
    if (x >= 16 || pad) {
        dest = itohexa_helper(dest, x/16, pad);
        pad = 1;
    }
    *dest++ = "0123456789ABCDEF"[x & 15];
    return dest;
}

char *itohexa(char *dest, uint16_t x) {
    uint8_t padding = (x < 0x1000);
    *itohexa_helper(dest, x, padding) = '\0';
    return dest;
}
```

Wouldn't the `padding` and `pad` in this case still go through the conversion even if the value had the first 4 most significant bits of the value as zeroes?
Just for the record: The modifications done to the code above still yield the same result as the original mentioned in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44549691/10035529) linked above.

Comment: You know you need exactly `4` "digits" ... so do a `for (int digit = 0; digit < 4; digit++) { /* your code suitably changed */ }`! rather than recurse.

Comment: `dest[4] = '\0': for (int i = 3; 0 <= i; --i, x >>= 4) dest[i] = "0123456789ABCDEF"[x & 0xF]:`

Comment: Re “However, this function gives me this instead: `4CE`”: I do not see how that can be true. Since `x < 0x1000`, `itohexa_helper` is called with `pad` set to 1, and it calls itself with the same value of `pad`, so infinite recursion occurs, and the program should crash when the stack is exhausted. Did you post the same code you executed?

Comment: Curious... Why use `0x1000` at one point in the code, but `15` and `16` elsewhere? Code would be much more clear sticking to hexadecimal constants...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @EricPostpischil I mixed up the types for `pad` and `padding`. I've corrected this now.

Comment: The types are not the issue. The code in the question does not produce the result you say it does. It crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it's just *fun* to use (more complex) recursion to solve a problem than it is to use iteration. You were close with your code!

It's not so much "padding" you want as it is leading '0's. Setting, clearing the padding flag might work (if done correctly) but only give you one leading zero.

Here's your code reworked:

```
static char *itohexa_helper( char *dest, uint16_t x, int n ) {
    if( --n )
        dest = itohexa_helper( dest, x>>4, n ); // recursion
    *dest++ = "0123456789ABCDEF"[x & 0xF]; // mask and offset
    return dest;
}

char *itohexa(char *dest, uint16_t x) {
    *itohexa_helper( dest, x, 4 ) = '\0'; // 4 digits of output...
    return dest;
}

int main( void ) {
    char buf[16]; // big enough

    puts( itohexa( buf, 0xBEEF ) );
    puts( itohexa( buf, 0xCDE ) );
    puts( itohexa( buf, 0xCD ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
BEEF
0CDE
00CD
```

Notice the absence of any base10 constants...

---

**EDIT**
If you're 100% sure (that's 0x0064 %) that you want 4 hex digits as a C string, there's this: (And it's 1 instruction shorter than the code of my rival in this friendly jostling match... :-)

```
char *itohexa(char *dest, uint16_t x) {
    // NB: index values shown are suitable for little endian processors.
    char *hex = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    union {
        uint16_t ui16;
        uint8_t c[2];
    } combo;
    dest[4] = '\0';
    combo.ui16 = ( x & 0x0F0F );
    dest[3] = hex[ combo.c[0] ];
    dest[1] = hex[ combo.c[1] ];
    combo.ui16 = ( x & 0xF0F0 )>>4;
    dest[2] = hex[ combo.c[0] ];
    dest[0] = hex[ combo.c[1] ];

    return dest;
}
```

You may have to play with the array indices, depending on big-/little-endian-ness of the MCU. What fun!!

Comment: "Sometimes it's just fun to use (more complex) recursion to solve a problem than it is to use iteration." Yeah well, the resulting assembler is often less fun though, since recursion tends to produce horribly inefficient code. And that's what clang 17 produces given this particular code, while gcc 13.2 somewhat managed to unroll it but replaces it with multiple function calls to some name-mangled thing.

Comment: @Lundin The OP may have been using this task as a learning exercise to conquer Mt. Recursion in order to have more intuition when facing a problem (like "permutation") that has a _natural_ recursive solution... Who's to say? :-)

Comment: Thank you! This worked. @Lundin 's answer is good too. But since I'm working on a microcontroller, I'm a little short on tokens.

Comment: @Boyfinn MCU, eh? I don't know what "short on tokens" means... Anyway, glad to lend a hand. Whether this is efficient (or not) needs to be benchmarked...

Comment: @Boyfinn Using recursion on a microcontroller is a cardinal sin and often banned by all known coding standards. But if ignoring that, take both versions, show it into your MCU IDE, enable optimizations and hit disassembly. Count the amount of instructions the amount of function calls, the rough stack usage. Then I dare with some confidence say you'll pick my version.

Comment: (For high end MCUs > Cortex M4 then also look at the number of branches.)

Comment: @Lundin I'm on MSP430G2231. I know It's completely obsolete but that's what I'm stuck with for now. After testing your code, I get a slightly higher RAM usage (of 2 bytes), But i save 14 bytes of flash. (i guess since i have to replace all direct references to `booleans` with 1&0 because that Isn't recognized as a type by the default compiler)

Comment: @Lundin I'm not sure yet which solution I'm going to stick with, since I have to do some more testing. But thank you anyways for your input and marvelous code!

Comment: @Boyfinn That's static RAM use, not stack depth. And well, obvioulsy you could optimize my code further for tiny microcontrollers - replace `size_t` with `uint8_t` and basic stuff like that.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah, I already did that, Since `size_t` Isn't even defined in the microcontroller's version of `stdint.h`. Another thing for efficiency in my case would be to decrement the for loop instead of incrementing, since the MSP architecture likes detecting zeroes better.

Comment: @Boyfinn `size_t` sits in stddef.h. As for decrementing loops comparing vs zero, that's some 1980s programming manual optimization. If your compiler can't do simple stuff like that for you and it matters for your target, then your compiler is very bad. Did you actually enable optimizations?

Comment: "Notice the absence of any base10 constants..." --> 16 in `char buf[16];` ?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Got me... Shudda gone with `8` as I was thinking about doing... :-)

Comment: "depending on big-/little-endian-nes" disclaimer deserves to be a code comment as it is easy to miss.

Comment: I suspect code footprint is a tad smaller with `char hex[16] = "0123456789ABCDEF";`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Tried `hex[16]` with gcc. Might have saved 1 byte of data... Not sure, cause it's been decades since I worked with Assembler... Odd, to me, that Clang emitted fewer instructions... Seems OP knows what they want/need with their particular setup... Cheers! (Applied your "in code comment" suggestion. Thanks! `:-)`)

Answer (score 1):

A simply non-recursive approach: build the string up from the least significant digit to the most.

```
#include <stdint.h>

char *itohexa(char *dest, uint16_t x) {
  int place = 4;
  dest[place] = '\0';
  while (place > 0) {
    dest[--place] = "0123456789ABCDEF"[x & 15];
    x >>= 4;
  }
  return dest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write it all out as explicit as possible, like this (explanations in comments):

```
#define ZERO_PAD false

char* itohexa (char dest[4+1], uint16_t x)
{
  bool remove_zeroes = true;
  char* ptr = dest;

  for(size_t i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    // mask out the nibble by shifting 4 times byte number:
    uint8_t nibble = (x >> (3-i)*4) & 0xF; 
    
    // binary to ASCII hex conversion:
    char hex_digit = "0123456789ABCDEF" [nibble];
    
    if(!ZERO_PAD && remove_zeroes && hex_digit == '0')
    {
      ; // do nothing
    }
    else
    {
      remove_zeroes = false;
      *ptr = hex_digit;
      ptr++;
    }
  }

  if(remove_zeroes) // was it all zeroes?
  {
    *ptr = '0';
    ptr++;
  }
  *ptr = '\0';

  return dest;
}
```

Test case:

```c
char dest[4+1];
puts(itohexa(dest, 0));
puts(itohexa(dest, 1230));
puts(itohexa(dest, 0));
puts(itohexa(dest, 0xC1));
puts(itohexa(dest, 0xABBA));
```

Output `ZERO_PAD false`:

```
0
4CE
0
C1
ABBA
```

Output `ZERO_PAD true`:

```
0000
04CE
0000
00C1
ABBA
```

`ZERO_PAD` can naturally be made a parameter instead, or you can make two different functions etc.

Comment: And as a bonus the resulting machine code from this looks far more efficient than the recursion toy program. 25 instructions (x86_64) and 100% branch free, goddang it gcc, good job!

Comment: Question: My answer (yesterday) https://stackoverflow.com/a/77313793/17592432 included extracting nibbles out of a `uint16_t`... I'd appreciate your comment on that `do/while()` loop compared to your version here... Thanks...

Comment: @Fe2O3 Well, the mainstream compilers produce some very hard to read disassmbly for that one, not easy to dissect... The do-while loop results in several branches because of the many comparison operators, so if avoiding branching is important, it should probably be re-worked to reduce the amount of branches somehow.